# How to minimize an application to system tray?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to minimize an application to system tray?

My application is developed in C#.Net. I have written code such that the Form minimizes to system tray if a button is clicked after selecting some settings from comboboxes. The button gets disabled after clicking once. So, I can't use that button to minimize the Form again. The Form pops up when a RichTextBox is populated with data received from COM port. Everything is working fine.

The problem is when the minimized Form pops up after it receives serial data I need an option to minimize it back to system tray again so that it can pop up again when new data is populated in the RichTextBox.

I don't want to add another button to do this whenever Form pops up. Is there any other way to do it?

It would be better if somebody provides code so that the app minimizes to system tray if minimize button in the title bar is clicked.

I just want to know the function name I have to use, something like `private Form1_Resize()`. Actually, Resize event can't be used because it triggers whenever form is minimized or maximized. I need it to trigger only when Form minimized.

Comment: You can enable the button again when form popups

Comment: Your only problem is the button being disabled? Just reenable it once the form reappears.

Comment: Do you mean 'minimise to taskbar' or 'hide and show a notification icon'? Task bar icons are the big ones close to the start button, notification icons are the small ones near to the date/time.

Comment: No, I don't have problem with the code for minimizing to sysTray or popping up. I can't renable the button used initially because it is used to open COM port. So once it is clicked the COM port opens and Form minimizes to SysTray. When data is received and populated in RichTextBox the Form pops up. Once the button is clicked COM port will be open all time so the button (Connect button) will be disabled. I need a method or function which can be used to minimize the app to SysTray when Form's minimize button in title bar is clicked. I just need the event that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: If I press the close button (X button) on title bar the app closes the  COM port if it is already open and then exits normally. Why that question? I am not a professional .Net programmer. I am an embedded designer and programmer. Here is the link for my project. How can I improve the code so that it looks more professional? [url]https://mega.co.nz/#!Fwh0kY6D!pJG8QLXstD9FIDU4WjHsGURwcLMyozzhVinrmFRXB84[/url]

Answer (score 1):

There are thousand of HowTo's out there, did you try Google? Just one example: http://alperguc.blogspot.de/2008/11/c-system-tray-minimize-to-tray-with.html

Comment: Thank you everybody. This was what I needed. I was using my code in Form_Resize event handler function but I was not testing for the condition    if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)  .  So, it was trying to minimize whenever Form was resized that is whenever the form tried to minimize and also when trying to pop up.  I used     private void frmMain_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
 {
 //My code to minimize to SysTray here
 }

}     Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a key to minimize the form?

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But my problem got solved. I feel it is better to use minimize button of Form's title bar to minimize the app to SysTray. :)

Comment: I assumed you didn't want them enabled as it seemed to obvious. :) What happens if you press the close button?

Comment: If I press the close button (X button) on title bar the app closes the  COM port if it is already open and then exits normally. Why that question?

Comment: I assumed the window was only a notification window, in which case you should take care what happens if you close it as enabling minimize also enables the close button. For this size application it's completely fine to put everything in the main form.

Comment: Here is the link for my VC# app. https://mega.co.nz/#!Fwh0kY6D!pJG8QLXstD9FIDU4WjHsGURwcLMyozzhVinrmFRXB84       I have only one Form and its Maximize button is disabled. It is like a fixed size dialog box.  Yes, both (_) and (X)... minimize and Close buttons in title bar are needed. I just wanted my app to minimize to tray after opening the COM port and wait till the TextBox gets populated with new SMS received and also wanted my app to popup after SMS is displayed. But I wanted to minimize it to tray after it pops up everytime which is now solved.

Comment: I have another problem. I built the app using VS 2008 for x86 on my Win 7 32 bit system. It works fine for me but the app hangs sometimes in my friends system which is win 8 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void frmMain_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
{
 mynotifyicon.Visible = true;
 mynotifyicon.ShowBalloonTip(500);
 this.Hide();
}
 else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
 {
 mynotifyicon.Visible = false;
 }
}
```